# Flow Component Number Input Doesn't Display

Tags: visual-workflow, screen-flow

I have a screen flow that has a number input field that simply does not display when I debug. There is no visual display logic around it (I have removed it)

It's label is `Quantity` and it's API name is `Quantity` - is there anyway to debug this?

[image]
[image]

Note: Initially it works fine - but if I try to modify it's "Set Component Visibility" logic to be displayed only when "Quantity Range" checkbox's API Value is "False" or "Null" it disappears